# How to create a Error Log file with Javascript in Chrome

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a log file everytimes a error occurs in my code. 
So far i have researched on internet, i could only find doing it with ActivexObject which only works in IE.
I want javascript to work in chrome. Do anyone know how i can do it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You cannot access the user's file system from javascript, just imagine what would happen if you could

Comment: Post the error report to your server? seems better than having data on the client side (which you could use localStorage to achieve)

Comment: as Alex told you, posting error data to a server every X seconds could be a solution

Comment: Yes, i dont know what could happen, atleast my problem would be solved . Anyways, i cannot report to server yet. My app cannot communicate to server as of now, everything is clientside.
I will try using localStorage or with cookies.